# "Call not sent" when trying to call someone on Moto G running Android Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, calls, motorola-moto-g

I have a Moto G upgraded to Android Lollipop from Android 4.4.4 KitKat. I can send SMS and receive calls. But, whenever I dial a number or try to call someone, I get this message:

> Call not sent

What can I do?

Comment: Allright, after getting the phone back I got the issue again today. I turned the phone OFF and ON, then signal came back normally and I was able to phone.

Comment: What worked for me was a suggestion on [GSM Arena](http://www.gsmarena.com/newscomm-11484.php) that you should turn off the phone, take sim out, turn phone on, put sim. After that you can make calls. I had this on HTC One M7 (custom Lollipop ROM).

Answer (score 4):

Under "Mobile network settings", I switched "Preferred network type" from 3G to 2G, and rebooted the phone. I was then able to make calls again.
Then I switched back to 3G and rebooted, and it still works.

Odd...

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what Talltony said, I had to go to

`Settings -> Wireless & networks -> More -> Cellular networks -> Preferred network type`

and **select 3G** as there was nothing selected after the update.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings - > Select your network and reboot. Hope this will work!

Comment: Can you be more specific about where you do this within Settings?